# Sorting an email log file from the last 2 years. Trying to find unique entries by user email

Tags: sorting, unix, sed, terminal, grep

I'm trying to sort an email log file.  Each line of the file looks like:

```
deliver(jsmith): May 17  >: saved mail to INBOX
deliver(bdillon): May 17  >: saved mail to INBOX
```

jsmith and bdillon are the emails.

Basically what I'd like to do is trim this file to only show one instance of jsmith.  So if jsmith sent multiple emails on May 17, how would I delete all but one of those lines?

I'd like to do this for every email entry, so there is only one entry for jsmith, bdillon, tjones, etc...

Comment: you'd have to read the file backwards until you hit Jan 01, otherwise you'd never be able to tell which Jan 01 you hit.

Comment: Would I do that in Vim?  It's a rather big file.  It has 400 million lines.

Comment: `0G?Jan 01`, basically. go to end of file, then search backwards for Jan 01. but you're trying to do accounting on the file, and vim's a text editor.

Comment: So what would be the best way to do this? I'm okay with terminal commands, but I am still a novice.

Comment: get a better logging system going so it includes the full year? that'd simplify all of this down the road.

Comment: Well yeah, that's going to change now.  But I need to work with what I have.  I'm trying to do a security audit to see who may have been trying to access email that does not work with the company in 2014, not the future.

Comment: so yeah. a script to read backwards from the end of the file until you hit the "last" Jan 01 entry. keep track of the usernames you encounter as you're scanning, and ... done. As long as you don't try doing this on Jan 2/2015, you'd only get 2014 entries in the "keep track" log.

Comment: Okay, I've deleted all lines previous to Jan 1, 2014.  Could you help me create unique entries?  For example.  If there are multiple entries for jsmith on May 17, how could I edit the file so only one entry shows up for May 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've now deleted all lines previous to Jan 1 2014. You can now assume that all matches between the email and day will be unique to 2014. Something like this should suffice to find all of the unique entries.

```
grep -o -P "\w+\((\w|\d)+\):\s+\w+\s+\d+" yourfile | sort | uniq > newfile
```

Note:

- -o means only keep what the grep finds on that line,
- -P means use perl style regular expression. The string is a perl
  regex matching text of the for `deliver(bdillon): May 17`,
- sort sorts the lines,
- uniq removes duplicates

This is assuming you only want a log with unique entries like

```
deliver(bdillon): May 17
deliver(jsmith): May 17
```

If the message is also needed remove the grep and just cat the file instead or call sort on it directly.